# Heroku hosted Flask SocketIO backend not working with separate front end?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn, flask-socketio

The idea is a backend that uses Flask SocketIO and is hosted on Heroku, and a separate frontend that can use this backend.

I can host the backend fine (I can tell it works because I added a simple Flask route that I can view at the Heroku app URL), but there's a lot of issues with the frontend connecting to the backend.

**server.py (backend using Flask SocketIO)**

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*', engineio_logger=True, logger=True)

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('Message: ' + msg)
    send(msg, broadcast=True)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>This is the index</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

**index.html (separate frontend)**

(Also not sure if the bit within `io.connect` should be http, https, wss, but I tried all three with the same results)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Room</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-nYuHvSAhY5lFZ4ixSViOwsEKFvlxHMU2NHts1ILuJgOS6ptUmAGt/0i5czIgMOahKZ6JN84YFDA+mCdky7dD8A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('wss://young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com/');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send('User has connected!');
    });

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });

    $('#sendbutton').on('click', function() {
        socket.send($('#myMessage').val());
        $('#myMessage').val('');
    });

});
</script>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<input type="text" id="myMessage">
<button id="sendbutton">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens is a TON of errors in the frontend's dev console: Mainly `400 (BAD REQUEST)`s, but also a lot of `WebSocket connection to '<URL>' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established`. Once in a while I'll see `Received message`, which means the frontend successfully connected to the backend, but then after that the same errors will continue displaying.

**Procfile**

`web: gunicorn server:app`

I'm not sure where the Heroku logs really "begin", but here's a chunk of the logs:

```
2021-11-30T18:29:46.288972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro6z5m&sid=NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=cf82a068-664a-4d8c-9143-85070cf7c2cd fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23649ms status=400 bytes=276 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:46.284545+00:00 app[web.1]: HPmyKr8vdxbU4f1gAAAq: Sending packet PING data None
2021-11-30T18:29:46.285088+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.94.221 - - [30/Nov/2021:18:29:46 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro6yq6&sid=HPmyKr8vdxbU4f1gAAAq HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "http://localhost:5500/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-11-30T18:29:46.285645+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid session NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs
2021-11-30T18:29:46.285985+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.24.245 - - [30/Nov/2021:18:29:46 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro6z5m&sid=NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs HTTP/1.1" 400 17 "http://localhost:5500/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-11-30T18:29:46.286451+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid session NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs
2021-11-30T18:29:46.286802+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.95.96 - - [30/Nov/2021:18:29:46 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro6z5k&sid=NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs HTTP/1.1" 400 17 "http://localhost:5500/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472483+00:00 app[web.1]: NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs: Failed websocket upgrade, expected UPGRADE packet, received None instead.
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472867+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-30 18:29:46 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472868+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472869+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472869+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472870+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 194, in handle_request
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472870+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472870+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 626, in reraise
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472871+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472872+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 185, in handle_request
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472872+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp.write(item)
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472873+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 326, in write
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472873+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.send_headers()
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472873+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 322, in send_headers
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472874+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.write(self.sock, util.to_bytestring(header_str, "latin-1"))
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472874+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 287, in write
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472874+00:00 app[web.1]:     sock.sendall(data)
2021-11-30T18:29:46.472875+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
2021-11-30T18:29:46.285740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro6z5k&sid=NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=4900fc50-0027-4140-bc7c-decfd52d1684 fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23646ms status=400 bytes=276 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:46.285836+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro6yq6&sid=HPmyKr8vdxbU4f1gAAAq" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=64ebc4b0-81a5-4d8b-a66a-3871dd308e6f fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24795ms status=200 bytes=265 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:46.479546+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=NDhJT0z96qLOucrWAAAs" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=5ddd2737-7437-4cb4-94b4-7aeda8dbdf1c fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23900ms status=101 bytes=202 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:47.292647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro737D" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=8ec81170-0580-48ee-a288-78cf9aa7b5e8 fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=362 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:47.410920+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro738j&sid=Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=131ec4ae-50f0-4468-a022-e2508d3a421c fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=276 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:47.291224+00:00 app[web.1]: Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
2021-11-30T18:29:47.291871+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.94.221 - - [30/Nov/2021:18:29:47 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro737D HTTP/1.1" 200 97 "http://localhost:5500/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-11-30T18:29:47.391407+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid session Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs
2021-11-30T18:29:47.391783+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.94.221 - - [30/Nov/2021:18:29:47 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro738g&sid=Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs HTTP/1.1" 400 17 "http://localhost:5500/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-11-30T18:29:47.410001+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid session Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs
2021-11-30T18:29:47.410470+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.24.245 - - [30/Nov/2021:18:29:47 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro738j&sid=Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs HTTP/1.1" 400 17 "http://localhost:5500/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-11-30T18:29:47.489672+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid session Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs
2021-11-30T18:29:47.490037+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.94.221 - - [30/Nov/2021:18:29:47 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro73AQ&sid=Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs HTTP/1.1" 400 17 "http://localhost:5500/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-11-30T18:29:47.490707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro73AQ&sid=Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=3e36cba7-1de6-435c-914f-9fbefcd7758c fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=276 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:47.392465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nro738g&sid=Ehmhduh_5Wnt0SgHAAAs" host=young-scrubland-90415.herokuapp.com request_id=c6fab832-5bf5-4ed4-ab0c-0be04444275e fwd="174.243.112.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=276 protocol=https
2021-11-30T18:29:49.291443+00:00 app[web.1]: 4sYf-4nVDG980gzKAAAt: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '4sYf-4nVDG980gzKAAAt', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
2021-11-30T18:29:49.291665+00:00 app[web.1]: EGCwP7PO8ItOkmLtAAAo: Client is gone, closing socket
2021-11-30T18:29:49.291829+00:00 app[web.1]: EGCwP7PO8ItOkmLtAAAo: Client is gone, closing socket
```

I've been googling and googling for hours (did maybe 2-3 hours yesterday, and I'm somewhere between 2-3 hours today working on this) and haven't made much progress. I PRAY that someone here will be able to help.

Comment: The troubleshooting section of the Flask-SocketIO docs provide instructions on how to enable logging. Do that, and then update your Heroku logs, as the section of logs that you pasted does not include enough information to diagnose the problem. Also, when you are reading the docs, review the deployment section that applies to your situation to make sure you are doing everything correctly. The Gunicorn command you have here looks wrong to me.

Comment: @Miguel I'm not totally understanding what you're saying. As far as the logging goes, do you mean the `engineio_logger` and/or `logger`  keyword args when initializing the `SocketIO` object? I set both of those to True, and I'm not sure what other logging options you're referring to.

As far as the incorrect Gunicorn command, I've since changed the Procile to 

```web: gunicorn -k gevent -w 1 server:app``` (from the docs). But I'm still having issues, and I don't understand Gunicorn or gevent or any of that well enough to know where to go from here.

Comment: @Miguel I'm also not sure which part of the logs I need to paste. I did a whole new Heroku app, and tried to copy all of the logs (since the app has only been up for maybe 10 minutes at this point), but it's too many characters to add to the original post. So here's a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/0WdMxq0E. It definitely feels lazy for me to just copy and paste the entire log and ask you to sort through it, but like I said, I don't know which part(s) are relevant :/

Comment: Did you notice in the logs that Socket.IO says "server initialized for eventlet"? Yet you are using gevent. That is very likely part of the problem. Remove eventlet, or else explcitly tell Socket.IO that you want to use gevent. See the `async_mode` option in the docs for more info on this.